# Parse a puppet manifest with Python

Tags: python, string, file, puppet

I have a puppet manifest file - init.pp for my puppet module
In this file there are parameters for the class and in most cases they're written in the same way:

**Example Input:**

```
class test_module(
    $first_param = 'test',
    $second_param = 'new' )
```

What is the best way that I can parse this file with Python and get a dict object like this, which includes all the class parameters?

**Example output:**

```
param_dict = {'first_param':'test', 'second_param':'new'}
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 4):

[Puppet Strings](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-strings#readme) is a rubygem that can be installed on top of Puppet and can output a JSON document containing lists of the class parameters, documentation etc.

After installing it (see above link), run this command either in a shell or from your Python program to generate JSON:

```
puppet strings generate --emit-json-stdout init.pp
```

This will generate:

```
{
  "puppet_classes": [
    {
      "name": "test_module",
      "file": "init.pp",
      "line": 1,
      "docstring": {
        "text": "",
        "tags": [
          {
            "tag_name": "param",
            "text": "",
            "types": [
              "Any"
            ],
            "name": "first_param"
          },
          {
            "tag_name": "param",
            "text": "",
            "types": [
              "Any"
            ],
            "name": "second_param"
          }
        ]
      },
      "defaults": {
        "first_param": "'test'",
        "second_param": "'new'"
      },
      "source": "class test_module(\n    $first_param = 'test',\n    $second_param = 'new' ) {\n}"
    }
  ]
}
```

(JSON trimmed slightly for brevity)

You can load the JSON in Python with `json.loads`, and extract the parameter names from `root["puppet_classes"]["docstring"]["tags"]` (where `tag_name` is `param`) and any default values from `root["puppet_classes"]["defaults"]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression (straightforward but fragile)

```
import re
def parse(data):
    mm = re.search('\((.*?)\)', data,re.MULTILINE)
    dd = {}
    if not mm:
        return dd
    matches = re.finditer("\s*\$(.*?)\s*=\s*'(.*?)'", mm.group(1), re.MULTILINE)
    for mm in matches:
        dd[mm.group(1)] = mm.group(2)
    return dd
```

You can use it as follows:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(filename,'r') as ff:
     dd = parse(ff.read())
```

Comment: Only problem with this is that the regexp will also capture all other variables and assumes a space in between the assignment operator (which is true for 99% of cases, but still). Otherwise, this works nicely.

Comment: Well, this is the fragile part :-)

Comment: Don\`t forget to ignore comments (line that starts with `#`)

Comment: Actually I tried that and it didn't work. Can you explain how to use re or what did you try to do?

Comment: You should read the contents of the file and provide it the function. Basically, we first search for the '(' and ')' and in it, we search for $var = 'value'

Comment: What is the data you expect to get? A string?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the "best" way, but one way would be:

1)  Set up Rspec-puppet (see google or [my blog post](http://razorconsulting.com.au/setting-up-puppet-module-testing-from-scratch-part-i-puppet-syntax-puppet-lint-and-rspec-puppet.html) for how to do that).
2)  Compile your code and generate a Puppet catalog. See [my other blog](http://razorconsulting.com.au/dumping-the-catalog-in-rspec-puppet.html) post for that.

Now, the Puppet catalog you compiled is a JSON document.

3)  Visually inspect the JSON document to find the data you are looking for. Its precise location in the JSON document depends on the version of Puppet you are using.

4)  You can now use Python to extract the data as a dictionary from the JSON document.